# Wordpress Comments - Divide by conversation like Medium.com

Tags: comments

For ex, in medium.com the comments are divided by conversation like this:

[image]

How can I **divide the WP comments by conversation** so even if there are more than two people involved, I would like them to appear one after another?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This kind of comments drilldown needs custom coding, have you tried e.g. css+js ? Maybe REST API could be used in more advanced solutions.

Comment: I can go for custom coding and CSS/JS is fine for me. I'm looking for help in the WP PHP side?